# Embed google doc without publishing

Tags: iframe, embed, google-slides

I would like to embed a Google Slides presentation with an iframe. Anyone with the link can view it but I do not want to publish it to the web.

Answer (score 1):

The "[Publish to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965)" option is specifically meant to embed the presentation within iframes so anyone with the link can view it, and it also gives you the iframe code, but I'm guessing that by "do not want to publish it to the web" you mean that you don't want the file to be indexed in Google searches.

According to [this support thread](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/45574805/cannot-share-file-publicly-after-new-share-interface-launched) to avoid getting indexed you can click the "Share" button and set the sharing option to "Anyone with the link":

[image]

Then to embed it within an iframe get the sharing link and replace `/edit` with `/embed` to it at the end. Example: `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<Slide_ID>/embed`.

The result looks the same as getting the "published" link, but it's not indexed by Google Search. Of course, keep in mind that it may still be found if the website where you embedded it is indexed.